# Color profile for projector messed up after Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, upgrade, color, projector

Yesterday I finally decided to upgrade to Lion from Snow Leopard on my 27" iMac (mid-2010 quad i7 model) and overall everything went fine, there is just one thing that bugs me.

Prior to the upgrade Snow Leopard had automagically chosen a color profile for my projector (Optoma HD100X) which I have connected to the Mini-DP port via a Mini-DP-to-HDMI adapter. This color profile worked great with the projector.

After the upgrade the projector is using a different color profile which appears to have significantly lower quality output. Cyan and light blue colors look washed out, magenta, red and yellow all trend toward more brownish tones and I can't quite pin it down but it feels like something is just wrong with the contrast and gamma.

I've tried calibrating the profile and I've tried tweaking the settings on my projector, even tried using other color profiles but somehow something just seems "off", like the mac is now forcing output into a smaller color gamut.

Has anyone heard of similar problems with Lion? Has anyone managed to fix problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm having exactly the same problem. Check System Preferences > Displays > Color, and see if you have more than one identically-named profile. A possible workaround for this problem is to select another profile and then the original one.